# Snowflake - a union condition of integer and varchar types lead to decimal datat type of a column

Tags: integer, decimal, union, varchar

Input: we have two tables with ID fields. In one table this field has an integer data type, in another - a varchar. And when we combine these data with a union/union all condition, the output data type of the column is decimal.

Do you have any explanations for this type choosing? Maybe you know any other rules to predict output data type?

To reproduce this behavior you can use the script below:

```
select typeof(ID)
from (
         SELECT '12345'::integer ID
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '12345'::varchar ID
     ) as lt;
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUUB9.png)